# Comment renderer bug?

Tags: bug, status-completed, comments, markdown

Is there a bug in the renderer for comments wherein "`Foo`s" will not render with "Foo" in a monospaced font if followed by non-whitespace? See the comment below for an example.

Comment 1: Test: "\`Foo\`s". Result: `Foo`s.

Result here: Test: "`Foo`s". Result: `Foo`s.

Result below: Test: "`Foo`s". Result: `Foo`s.

Comment 2: You have to `Frobber` the `Foo`s using a `Bar`.

Result here: You have to `Frobber` the `Foo`s using a `Bar`.

Comment: Test: "\`Foo\`s". Result: `Foo`s.

Comment: You have to `Frobber` the `Foo`s using a `Bar`.

Answer (score 1):

With the [recent changes in comment markdown](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/79546/can-we-please-have-a-place-where-changes-to-the-markdown-syntax-are-documented/79981#79981), code in comments now works almost exactly as in questions/answers, so this works now.