# How to write a slash in inline code thing

Tags: support, comments, code-formatting

Tried to add a comment to a post today, which ended up looking rather weird. What I had typed was:

```
On windows I believe you need to use `\` instead of `/`
```

As you can see in the first comment to this question, I don't exactly end up with what I thought I would... What's going on here?

Tried various combinations of double `\\` and double `` (which seems to be impossible to have in an inline code thing...?), but couldn't get a good result. Ended up putting a space after the slash, which at least made it readable. Problem then was that the space between the inline code and the word "instead" seems to disappear O.o

Comment: On windows I believe you need to use `\` instead of `/`

Comment: On windows I believe you need to use ``\`` instead of `/`

Comment: Original: `\` instead of `/`

Comment: Double slash: `\\` instead of `/`

Comment: Double thingy: `\`` instead of `/`

Comment: Space after slash: `\ ` instead of `/`

Answer (score 7):

See [my answer here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/79546/can-we-please-have-a-place-where-changes-to-the-markdown-syntax-are-documented/79981#79981):

The simplest thing is to use two or more backticks to enclose the code block; this will disable any and all escaping:

> ``` On windows I believe you need to use ``\`` instead of `/` ```

Comment: Test: ``\`` instead of `/`

Comment: Do you know where the backtick is on a standard mac keyboard running OSX SL?

Comment: @mplungjan: that's a new question and probably best off at http://superuser.com

Comment: @mplungjan, depending on the definition of "standard": mine has it below the tilde, to the left of the Z key. Most/many others have that same key below the Esc.

Comment: I commented because I wanted to know this in this question - actually in all questions mentioning a backtick

Comment: @Arjan, I do know. I was asking whoever viewed this answer ;)