# Post `\` or `\\` in a comment

Tags: support, comments, markdown, code-block

I wanted to add to an answer that `\` should be escaped but I didn't manage to put this in a comment.

When I did:

```
`\`
```

then it didn't display the `\`, and:

```
`\\`
```

causes it to only display one `\` without formatting.

I did not seem to be able to post `\` or `\\`. Is this by design or not, and is there a way to actually write `\` or `\\` in a comment?

Comment: I also had problem but I think `\\\` this works? - hmm half right That's 3 slashes in the backticks and shows only 2 with the ticks.. not formatted but at least 2 show ;)

Comment: ``\`` you mean?

Comment: @JeffAtwood but without highlight..

Answer (score 8, accepted):

see [Can we please have a place where changes to the markdown syntax are documented?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/79546/can-we-please-have-a-place-where-changes-to-the-markdown-syntax-are-documented/79981#79981)

> There is no escaping at all in multi-backtick code. Start a code block with five backticks, and everything will appear verbatim until we find another run of (precisely) five backticks.

thus you want

```
 ``\``
```

which will produce

`\`

and for the record this is the same as it works in regular Markdown.

Answer (score 0):

> **Edit:** this is mainly an observation I discovered and is not an acceptable solution, it is million times inferior to the current
>   accepted answer as you need sometimes escape and sometimes not, so it
>   is not recommended

When the slash(es) inside backticks **in comments** (this doesn't happen in Qs or As) do not have anything after them, you need to escape them:

```
`\\` will display `\`
`\\\` will display `\\`
...
```

but if you have anything after, you do *not* need to escape:

```
`\\hi` will display `\\hi`
`\\\hi` will display `\\\hi`
...
```

Comment: Nether `\\` nor `\\\` works..