# `\` isn't rendered correctly in comment area?

Tags: bug, comments, markdown, rendering

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Post `\` or `\\` in a comment](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/92171/post-or-in-a-comment)

I just found that `\` cannot rendered correctly (without highlight around it) in comment area. When I'm leaving a comment in [THIS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12851980/ios-push-message-contains-special-character) question. Is this a bug or not? How can I input the `\` in comment area?

Comment: If [this question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/92171/post-or-in-a-comment) doesn't help, we're gonna need a bit more information. Single backslashes should work fine in comments: \.

Comment: @ajax333221 When no backticks are involved, it should just work anyway. I'm going to reopen, leave a link to the possible dupe, and then step away from the internets cause I'm clearly failing at this hour of the night. :)

Comment: @AnnaLear thanks for your reply :)

Comment: @AnnaLear I'm sorry, the workaround of the question you gave still cannot work in comment area... only \ without highlight here..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not really sure what the problem is. On the question you link to, I see this:

[image: screenshot of the comment in question]

For the text you entered into the comment box, I see this:

[image: comment editing view of same comment, showing precisely the text that's displayed.]

That's 100% identical to what's displayed. And the comment I put below this answer has the same source text as what's displayed.

Comment: Two backslashes: \\ One backslash: \ The end.

Comment: Actually, I want to leave it with `` around \\ and \. `//` is rendered well (with highlight), but `\` not (as you see)..

Comment: What kind of "highlight" are you talking about? There is no highlight on the "//" in your comment on http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12851980/ios-push-message-contains-special-character.

Comment: oops, `//` is not rendered here either! Please take a look at  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12851980/ios-push-message-contains-special-character again, I leave a new comment that I want to do. :)

Comment: I have edited it to be correct. The answer is [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/92175/115866), so it was a duplicate after all.

Comment: Oh, that's it! I didn't try it in SO. Thanks! By the way, why it not works in meta.SO :?

Comment: It works the same way on SO and on Meta. Why do you say it doesn't work here?

Comment: What about ``\``?

Comment: Looks good to me. I think you're just confused by the fact that code in comments doesn't have such a pronounced background color on Meta as it does on SO.

Comment: _"doesn't have such a pronounced background color on Meta as it does on SO"_. Yes it is!