# Slash syntax in preformatted code

Tags: bug, comments, markdown

Inside a comment, when I write `\\`, it doesn't produce the same result as in questions.

The result I got was `\`.

Is this a bug?

Comment: Inside a comment, when I write: \\ it doesn't produce the same result as in questions

Comment: Inside a comment, when I write: `\\` it doesn't produce the same result as in questions

Comment: Ah, there it is.  Looks like the backslash is escaping the second backtick.

Comment: Nice! I wish I had known this before!

Comment: Test: `\\` (filler)

Comment: Additionally: [Post \`\\` or \`\\\` in a comment](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/92171)