# Cannot escape square closing bracket in inlined code in comment links

Tags: bug, status-completed, markdown, markdown-rendering

Fundamentally, I want to create this link in a comment and have it go to the right place: 
[`String(byte[],Charset)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/String.html#String(byte[],%20java.nio.charset.Charset))

source:

```
[`String(byte[],Charset)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/String.html#String(byte[],%20java.nio.charset.Charset))
```

Two issues emerge:

1. The actual link strips the square brackets (presumably because they're improperly encoded), this is livable but undesirable, I can url-encode them myself
2. Comments incorrectly fail to escape the brackets, leading to a messy rendering of:

[`String(byte[],Charset)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/String.html#String(byte%5B%5D,%20java.nio.charset.Charset))

Without the code format I recognize it's possible to escape the slashes, rendering correctly as [String(byte[],Charset)](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/String.html#String(byte[],%20java.nio.charset.Charset))

However, with inline code formatting *and* escaped slashes, I simply see the slashes:

[`String(byte\[\],Charset)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/String.html#String(byte%5B%5D,%20java.nio.charset.Charset))

Comment: e.g. [`String(byte[],Charset)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/String.html#String(byte[],%20java.nio.charset.Charset))

Comment: Note that it isn't switched to a link but rather a [name] next to an http://link.

Comment: I wish there was some way to count the number of people who have just tried to replicate (in these comments) your bug...

Comment: @M.: Lance tried at least 4 times, I saw 3 other alerts since then.

Comment: Note: they should be encoded according to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40568/square-brackets-in-urls).

Comment: @M.: Unfortunately Google is failing to encode them =/

Comment: So in other words, this: [`String(byte\[\],Charset)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/String.html#String(byte%5b%5d,%20java.nio.charset.Charset)) still fails.

Comment: @M.: precisely.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot escape *anything* in code spans (because you shouldn't have to), with one exception: If the code span is delimited by *single* backticks, you can escape backticks (for historical reasons). If it's enclosed by *multiple* backticks, e.g. ``` ``here is a backtick: ` <-- see?`` ```, you can't (and don't have to) escape anything anymore. See [this answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/79546/can-we-please-have-a-place-where-changes-to-the-markdown-syntax-are-documented/79981#79981) for more.

The fact that the closing bracket broke stuff was merely a bug; that's fixed in the next build. Your original version will then work, except for – as you noted – the requirement to url-encode brackets in the link.

```
[`String(byte[],Charset)`](http://example.org)
```

Comment: You are fast!!!

Comment: @balpha: The escaping of backticks `\`` in inline code in comments is _not_ purely for historical reasons. How else could I produce `\``?

Comment: @HendrikVogt: By enclosing the code in *multiple* backticks (like my example above). Until the change from the answer I linked to (on your question), multiple backtick blocks were not supported in comments, so *back then* the only way to have a backtick in code was escaping, and *for historical reasons* (call it backwards-compatibility if you will) we left that in. Try it in a post -- *real* Markdown doesn't have that escaping thing.

Comment: @balpha: Try it yourself: `\`\` \` \`\`` gives `` ` ``.

Comment: @balpha: And `\`\`\`\`\`` gives `````. The problem is that spaces are no longer allowed at the start and end of inline code in comments. (I wonder why!)

Comment: @HendrikVogt: Well yeah, but that's nothing new -- I'm also mentioning that in my answer. That's certainly not the reason for leaving backslash-escaping in.

Comment: @balpha: No, indeed not new. So I'm even more puzzled why you write "By enclosing the code in _multiple_ backticks" as an answer to my question "How else could I produce `\``?". (Ah, maybe this wasn't clear to you: I meant producing _this very inline code_ `\``, consisting of a single backtick. See, yesterday I was asked how one does this on meta.math.sx!)

Answer (score 2):

You can, but there's a couple things with your link.  The square brackets can be escaped with a `\`, but the link should also really [be encoded properly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40568/square-brackets-in-urls).  I will add a comment on this answer using the following, (note the `\[\]`):

`[String(byte\[\],Charset)](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/String.html#String(byte%5b%5d, java.nio.charset.Charset))`

---

After OP's edit:

Comments are parsed with mini-markdown, which intentionally supports a subset of the markdown syntax.  This is very much intentional, as comments are just for quick things and should not need the full formatting that markdown in posts use.

Comment: [String(byte\[\],Charset)](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/String.html#String(byte%5b%5d,%20java.nio.charset.Charset))

Comment: Your link fails to go to the right place, the square brackets are dropped from the actual href.

Comment: Further, escaping fails when using inline code ticks: [`String(byte\[\],Charset)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/String.html#String(byte%5B%5D,%20java.nio.charset.Charset))

Comment: @Rebecca, your link strips out the [].  I think you need to encode the [] to %5b%5d (But only in the actual link)

Comment: @MarkElliot Meh, copy/paste error, but just encode the url correctly.  I think you need to escape the code ticks too maybe?  Comments use mini-markdown which is only a subset of the markdown syntax that posts use.  They aren't meant for complicated formatting like this.

Comment: Eh, I shouldn't need to escape my code ticks, I want to link code format, e.g.: [`String(byte<>,Charset)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/String.html#String(byte%5B%5D,%20java.nio.charset.Charset))

Comment: Sorry, I've partially invalidated your answer by refining my question to be more accurate and more concise.

Comment: @MarkElliot, so...you've edited to be an exact dupe of http://stackoverflow.com/q/40568/181481?

Comment: @Rebecca: nope, I've edited to indicate that I cannot *both* escape slashes and use inline code formatting for links. My *actual* link contains the url-encoded square brackets, the issue is in the label.

Comment: @MarkElliot, you edited after my comment again.  I've now edited my answer to match...I think.

Answer (score 2):

So to get this to work, as @RebeccaChernoff noted, you must escape the [] in the link text and **encode** them in the link itself.  Check out this page on [URL Encoding](http://www.blooberry.com/indexdot/html/topics/urlencoding.htm).

**Update:** So what you want is achieved by this:

```
[`String(byte`\[\]`,Charset)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/String.html#String(byte%5b%5d,%20java.nio.charset.Charset))  note the double '`'
```

**Update 2:**

```
[`String(byte['\]',Charset)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/String.html#String(byte%5b%5d,%20java.nio.charset.Charset))
```

Will get you the opening bracket **but not the closing one.**  See below in comments.
(After experimenting for 30 minutes, this is the closest I can get.  See my last comment)

Comment: [String(byte\[\],Charset)](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/String.html#String(byte%5b%5d,%20java.nio.charset.Charset))

Comment: Yeah, that was a copy/paste fail on my part.  I edited.

Comment: My word.  Eight tries for me to get that link right!!.  eek.

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't resolve the problem as I'd like to use inline code formatting, too. (edited question to be more precise)

Comment: [`String(byte`\[\]`,Charset)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/String.html#String(byte%5b%5d,%20java.nio.charset.Charset))

Comment: That's close, but I want *code formatted* square brackets. Seeing as the behavior is unexpected I'd still call this a bug -- though maybe this is a (poor?) workaround.

Comment: So you want [`String(byte[],Charset)`] to link as above.  I can't get it to work.

Comment: [`String(byte[`\]`,Charset)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/String.html#String(byte%5b%5d,%20java.nio.charset.Charset))