# Direct links don't render when inside square-bracketed text, although the preview shows them correctly

Tags: bug, markdown, hyperlinks

Normally, pasting the URL of a Stack Exchange post (from the same site that you're posting on) results in it being rendered into hypertext showing the title of the post. This is a nice shortcut for linking between posts on the same site without needing the usual `[text](link)` palaver. For example, the following is just a directly pasted URL in this post: [Formatting Sandbox](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/3122/278659)

**This process does not work when the pasted link is within a sentence or paragraph all in square brackets.** [For example, the following link will not render properly even though it's the same pasted URL as above: https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/3122/278659 However, the preview shown before posting DOES show the link rendering properly.]

Comment: Tested [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/384591/278659) in the Sandbox if anyone wants to play around with it.

Comment: I think the following post reports the same bug: [Hyperlinks do not work if they are inside square brackets](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/378302/986753)

Comment: @TheAmplitwist: Per bad_coder's answer there, the current final-result behavior shown in the submitted post abides by the CommonMark specification... Though the preview is inconsistent with CommonMark, so that part is ostensibly the bug here.

Comment: @V2Blast Yeah, I understand brackets create formatting oddities, and I'd be more fine with this if the preview showed it not rendering correctly - at least then you'd know there was a problem before posting, and be able to fix it without doing many experimental edits.

Comment: It works if you backslash/escape the brackets. I've seen it happen before, in comments too, usually with nested brackets. [I added a second test to the sandbox](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/384591/276027)