# Inline code markdown is handled differently in questions/answers and comments

Tags: discussion, markdown, markdown-rendering, inline-code

In questions/answers, to put backticks within my inline code I have to enclose the whole thing in double backticks.

```
``cd `brew --prefix` ``
```

In comments I can escape backticks with backslashes. I can't use backslashes like this in questions/answers. This seems like a better solution, but is obviously inconsistent.

```
`cd \`brew --prefix\``
```

Any good insight?

Comment: Here's how these should really look when entering them, using the better comment-style escaping: `\`\`cd \`brew --prefix\` \`\`` (Q&A) and `\`cd \\`brew --prefix\\`\`` (comments) ... phew, that was a trip down the markdown wormhole!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're trying to do `inline code like this` you  should probably not do that.  The problem is that it's ambiguous — you can't tell whether the slash is supposed to be included in the code unless you force the use of `\\` to produce a slash or something.  No matter what you do, using surrounding characters will produce some sort of ambiguity like this.  Should three backticks be rendered as one block with a backtick inside it, or a block with a backtick following it, or a block with a backtick preceding it?  In this case the answer is none of the above: ```.  There's no simple way to make all 4 versions possible.

The solution with the "unnecessary" space seems good to me, though — it's certainly not changing the meaning of your examples.  But if needed, just don't use inline blocks.

Use a `<pre>` block like so:

````
` one backtick
` surrounded by one backtick `
`` two backticks
`` surrounded by two backticks ``
``` etc.
cd `brew --prefix`
````

Or simply indent by four spaces:

````
` one backtick
` surrounded by one backtick `
`` two backticks
`` surrounded by two backticks ``
``` etc.
cd `brew --prefix`
````

Comment: Yeah, but I want to do this inline! Thanks for the tip, though, I used it to format my question correctly since I couldn't get double backticks to escape inside inline code.

Comment: @SWrobel I've added some more detail.  For your examples using the extra space shouldn't harm anything, right?

Comment: Ok, thanks. I'm still curious why the markdown is different for comments and q/a though. It doesn't make sense.

Comment: @SWrobel Comments use a different restricted (mini) Markdown parser, which is why there's room for variation. This particular case seems like an issue with the normal Markdown parser though, but I'll need to check.

Comment: @SWrobel Correction. The normal Markdown parser is doing things the expected way, and the backslash escape in comments was [a workaround](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/72737/backticks-not-escaped-in-questions-answers-as-they-are-in-comments/79228#79228) from before the [correct syntax was supported in comments](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/79546/can-we-please-have-a-place-where-changes-to-the-markdown-syntax-are-documented/79981#79981). I imagine the rationale for the correct syntax is pretty much what Matthew Read described above.

Comment: @TimStone thanks, that pretty much answers it! I didn't realize that you could go beyond 2 backticks without needing to escape within inline code. Now, I guess my question changes to why this isn't all spelled out in the markdown docs?

Comment: @SWrobel: Because that's a level of detail that would probably be more confusing than helping. Note that our documentation links to the official markdown "spec", which [does mention this.](http://daringfireball.net/projects/markdown/syntax#code)