# Escaping error in code highlight?

Tags: support, comments, markdown

I've just wrote `C:\` in [a comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13557125/why-isnt-the-file-created-or-why-cant-the-path-be-found/13557165#comment18575434_13557165) and it wouldn't work. I had to write `C:\` (with a trailing space).

Am I too drunk, or is it a real bug?

Here on the question it seems to be working.

Comment: This is the workaround: `C:\ `. And these are bugous: `C:\` and `C:\\`.

Comment: Weird that the comment Markdown works differently than the post Markdown. I want to say this is by-design because it makes sense that you'd want a way to escape the backtick in case your inline code *contains* a backtick, but it doesn't seem to work that way in posts. I'd almost say the bug is the reverse.

Comment: I believe this is by design, as `\ ` escapes whatever is to the right of it, in this case a backtick.

Comment: @TimPost, @animuson: But with two back-slashes it doesn't work either: `C:\\`.

Comment: @desert69 Yeah, that's weird, you'd think `C:\\` would work then. I remember this coming up before but I can't seem to find the post that specifically addresses it, it could have been a side conversation on a related post.

Comment: Looks like comments go through different escaping process.

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd yeap. Surely that's because of the mini-Markup.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yeah, comment markdown and escaping is... weird. I've been shying aways from changing this, since it's been like this forever, so it may break a ton of old comments. On the plus side, backslash escaping of backticks in code spans *only* happens in one-backtick spans*. But since [these days](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/79546/can-we-please-have-a-place-where-changes-to-the-markdown-syntax-are-documented/79981#79981), comment Markdown supports Markdown's multi-backtick codespans, you can use that for achieving what you want:

```
There's something to be found in ``C:\``
```

<sub><sup>*That is a weird sentence.</sup></sub>

Comment: Let's see: ``C:\``. Hell yeah :) So this won't be corrected? Thanks, @balpha