# Backquotes inside backquoted code in comments

Tags: support, comments, code-formatting

Sometimes, when I write answers, I need to include backquotes as part of the code (not as formatting markup). This I can do by using four-spaced indent in the answer. However I can't find a way to achieve this in a comment. For example, I need to write

```
SELECT `20` FROM `table`
```

But in a comment, not in an answer. Is there a way to achieve this?

Comment: @hims056 Can you explain what/why you changed in the body of the question?  I agree with adding [comments] tag, but don't understand changes in the body.  Thanks.

Comment: Actually I did nothing but just removed extra space.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use multiple backticks as delimiters:

```
Note that ``Tuple`2`` is a valid type name.
```

displays

> Note that `` Tuple`2 `` is a valid type name.

both in posts and in comments. A consecutive run of backticks that has a different count than the number of backticks the codespan was started with will be displayed, not end the code span. Note the word "different": It can also be *more*:

```
`two `` backticks`
```

turns into

> ``` two `` backticks ```

Also see [this answer of mine](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/79546/can-we-please-have-a-place-where-changes-to-the-markdown-syntax-are-documented/79981#79981).

Comment: Yep, works perfectly.  Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You can do that....but it's not going to be beautiful. 
The following

```
`SELECT \`20\` FROM \`table\``
```

will result in what I think you're trying to include. That is, you will have to explicitly escape the back-ticks within the code.

Comment: I tried doing this, but the backslash was displayed and the backtick after it was taken as the end of code formatting mark.

Comment: Seems to work for me: `SELECT \`20\` FROM \`table\``